# Deleting rows if missing in some variable in Python Pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, missing-data, data-cleaning

I am trying to use Pandas to remove rows that contain missing ethnicity information, though I didn't get very far as I am new to Pandas.

Using 'print name[ethnic.isnull() == True]' I can visualize which are the people with missing ethnicity information. But ultimately I want to 1) record the index by appending the missing-ethnicity cases' indexes into the 'missing array', 2) then create a second frame by deleting all the row with index matched with those in the 'missing' array.

I am currently stuck in the 'for case in frame' loop, where I try to print names of those with missing ethnicity. But my program ends without error but without printing out anything.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
import numpy as np

### Remove cases with missing name or missing ethnicity information
def RemoveMissing():
    data = pd.read_csv("C:\...\sample.csv")
    frame = DataFrame(data)
    frame.columns = ["Name", "Ethnicity", "Event_Place", "Birth_Place", "URL"]

    missing = []
    name = frame.Name
    ethnic = frame.Ethnicity

    # Filter based on some variable criteria
    #print name[ethnic == "English"]
    #print name[ethnic.isnull() == True] # identify those who don't have ethnicity entry

    # This works
    for case in frame:
        print frame.Name

    # Doesn't work
    for case in frame:
        if frame.Ethnicity.isnull() is True:
            print frame.Name

RemoveMissing()
```

Comment: Couldn't you do something like missing = frame[frame['Ethnicity'].isnull()]   then good = frame.dropna()

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
# Create a var to check if Ethnicity is missing
index_missEthnic = frame.Ethnicity.isnull()
frame2 = frame[index_missEthnic != True]
```